# How can I determine co-ordinates of the lane?

Tags: opencv, coordinates, straight-line-detection

I am using opencv to determine coordinates the lane between two red lines like this:

Lane-detection:

[image]

It is not rectangle so I can't use `cv2.rectangle` to cover on it.
Does everyone have some ideas?

Comment: What’s wrong with using two lines? Just like in the image you shared.

Comment: The 2 lines form a 4-point polygon, so you can use `cv2.fillPoly`.